# PouchDB 409 conflict when adding doc.

Tags: javascript, database, express, couchdb, pouchdb

I am getting a strange conflict with pouchDB when adding a new document. The conflict arises when creating a new doc shortly after another is made. However if I wait ~5 minutes or so the conflict no longer occurs. I am very stuck with solving this.

I am using a express with node. 
Here is my method for adding an item. It is used in a router (see below)

```
//require stuff
...
//require pouch
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
//db setup
var db = new PouchDB('http://127.0.0.1:5984/db');

module.exports = {
      addItem: (req, res, next) => {
        //check body fields with express validator
        req.checkBody('firstname', "Invalid, please enter firstname").notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('lastname', "Invalid, please enter lastname").notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('address', "Invalid, please enter address").notEmpty();
        var phonenumber = req.body.phonenumber; //phone number is optional dont use express validator
        var errors = req.validationErrors();
        if (errors) {
          res.render('add', {
            errors: errors
          });
        }
        var newDoc = {
          _id: date.toString() ,
          firstname: req.body.firstname,
          lastname: req.body.lastname,
          address: req.body.address,
          phonenumber: phonenumber,
          dateAdded: moment(date).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")
        }

        db.put(
          newDoc
        ).then(function (response) {
          res.redirect('/feed');
        }).catch(function (err) {
          if (err){
            return next(err);
          }
        });
      },
    ...
   //more methods
}
...
//export module
```

router for adding

```
//require all the stuff
//post new item route
router.route('/feed/add').post(ActionController.addItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the pouchdb-upsert to fix this. https://github.com/pouchdb/upsert

and used the puIfNotExists method.

```
...
    //save item to array and db
    db.putIfNotExists({
      _id: date.toString(),
      firstname: req.body.firstname,
      lastname: req.body.lastname,
      address: req.body.address,
      phonenumber: phonenumber,
      dateAdded: moment(date).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")
    }).then(function () {
      return res.redirect('/feed');
    }).catch(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
    })
...
```